# Backbone - rest POST service is called more than once

Tags: ajax, rest, backbone.js

I have a problem when I call a REST service by POST to updates tables in MySQL.
I'm working with BackboneJS and when click Save button, call the service and passed POST parameters

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: rootURL,
    data: dataJson, //data send to REST service by POST
    cacheControl: "no-cache",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log("OK");
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data.msg);
    }
});
```

But the problem occurs when income and leave the editing screen. Assuming I made a change and it worked perfectly bringing me back a single "OK", when I go back into the editing screen and record again, I get twice the word "OK".

If I repeat this step to enter and exit the screen edition, duplicate responses are based on the number of times into the screen edition.

I don't know if it's a problem about I'm doing wrong with BackboneJS...?? I'm doing this:

```
editAdverts: function(){
    var editAdvertsView = new EditAdvertsView ();
    $('#container-page').append(editAdvertsView.render(idAdverts).el);
}
```

It can also be a topic of AJAX?

I hope someone can help me with this issue because I am not an expert in BackboneJS

Thanks a lot!
Diego

Comment: Please can you post as much code as possible, I believe you are having zombie views.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without more code but I'm pretty sure it's because you are creating a model each time you are using editAdvert.

Instead of creating a model each time just create one at the init of your view then call the fetch/save function anytime you need an update. Creating the model once is enough.

edit: zombies views is a good thing to check too as brent noticed in comment, we can't tell without more code.

Comment: I not feel the same error if I make a call with GET Ajax. Any thoughts that the problem is in the POST.

Answer (score 0):

This is de code about route:

```
    var Index = {
        start: function() {
            var list_view = new MainView();
        }
    };

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend ({
        routes: {
            'goAdvert'          : 'goAdvert'
        },

        goAdvert: function(){
            var viewAdvertsView = new ViewAdvertsView();
            $('#container-page').append(viewAdvertsView.render().el);
        }
    });

    var MainView= Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#contenedor-body'),

        initialize: function() {

            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            // here is the code about main page. It's not important!                
        },


    });     

    new AppRouter;
    Index.start();
    Backbone.history.start();
```

This is the viewAdvertsView.js

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'jqueryuniform', 
    'bootstrap',
    'handlebars',
    'jqueryDataTables',
    'dtBootstrap',
    '../../view/editAdvertsView',
], function($, _, Backbone, jqueryuniform, Bootstrap, Handlebars, JQueryDataTables, DtBootstrap, EditAdvertsView){

        var viewAdverts = Backbone.View.extend({

            events: {
                'click #edit'       : 'editAdvert'
            }


            editAdvert: function(){

                $('#container-page').empty();

                var idAdvert = $(event.target).data('id');

                editAdvertView = new EditAdvertsView();
                $('#container-page').append(editAdvertView.render(idAdvert).el);

            },

            render: function() {

                // load viewAdverts

            }           

        });     

        return viewAdverts;
    }
);
```

And this is editAdvertsView.js

```
define([
        'jquery', 
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'jqueryuniform', 
        'bootstrap',
        'handlebars',
        'jqueryDataTables',
        'functions',
        'sessionManage',
        'slimscroll',
        'jqueryCustomSlimscroll',
        'slimscrollMin',
        'jqueryblockui', 
        'text!../../html/editAdverts.html',
        'maps',
        'fancybox'
    ], function($, _, Backbone, jqueryuniform, Bootstrap, Handlebars, JQueryDataTables, 
                Functions, SessionManage, Slimscroll, JqueryCustomSlimscroll, SlimscrollMin, 
                Jqueryblockui, EditAdverts, Maps, Fancybox){

        var Advert= Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#container-page'),

            events: {
                'click #saveChanges'            : 'doSaveChanges'
            },

            doSaveChanges: function(){
                var data = null;

            var rootURL = "http://localhost/php/slim/slim/advert/update" + "?date=" + $.now();

                dataJson = {
                    id: $("#id").val(),
                    product: $("#product").val(),
                    price: $("#price").val(),
                    client: $("#client").val(),
                    country: $("#country").val(),
                    tel: $("#telephone").val(),
                    cel: $("#cellphone").val()
                };


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: rootURL,
                    data: dataJson,
                    cacheControl: "no-cache",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){

                        console.log("OK");          

                    error: function(data){

                        console.log(data.msg);          

                    }
                }
            },

            render: function(codInmueble) {

                var self = this;

                var editTemplate = Handlebars.compile(EditAdverts); 
                self.$el.html(editTemplate());

                return this;
            }           

        });     

        return Advert;
    }
);
```